# Which event has a higher probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Which event has a higher probability?

> $24$ rolls of 2 dice at once we get at least 2 $1$s

or

> one roll of 4 dice at once we get at least one $1$?

Comment: Please correct your question.  When you roll the two dice do you mean get two ones at once?  You don't say that.  As written we just need two ones out of the forty-eight numbers, which is very likely.

Comment: You could say "48 rolls of a single dice, at least two of them are ones"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a roll of four dice getting a single 1:

> $$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6^2}+\frac{5^2}{6^3}+\frac{5^3}{6^4}=\frac{671}{1296}$$, since I am doing the chance of it not giving a one all times, then invert that (take it away from one)

For 24 rolls of 2 dice (at once), or 48 rolls of a single dice you get at least 2 'ones':

> Well, chances of it happening is , $1-(\frac{25}{6^2})^{24}=$ something very close to $1$. I got these numbers by saying the chance thee is not a one, and taking it to the power of $24$ and finally inverting it.

---

> Well, these results show that $$\frac{671}{1296}< \approx1$$, so we know that:
>
> > The chance of getting at least two $1$s in 24 rolls of two dice is greater than getting four rolls of a dice, and we get a single one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. $1$ minus the probability that in 24 rolls of 2 dice we never get 2 ones (at once): $1-\left(\frac{6^2-1}{6^2}\right)^{24}$.

1 minus the probability that in 1 roll of 4 dice we never get one: $1-\left(\frac{6-1}{6}\right)^{4}$.

Which number is greater?

P.S. Both numbers are quite close to $0.5$.

Comment: okay, it's much more clear now.. I am just unsure with this $\left(\frac{6^2-1}{6^2}\right)^{24}$. Why is there $6^2-1$ ?

Comment: $6^2$ is the number of couples of values of two dice. With the "minus $1$" we exclude the case of two ones (if my interpretation of your question is correct...).

Comment: there are 11 cases of '1' in all the possibilties

Comment: My interpretation is: 24 rolls of two dice we get at least one time one&one (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_eyes)